# DAX PowerBI SUM from the beginning up to current date (input by user)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 4 tables `Calendar`, `Products`, `Region`, and `Sales`. Then I create the relationship between 4 tables through

- `Region.Region_code` -> `Sales.Region_Code`
- `Product.Product_wid` -> `Sales.Product_wid`
- `Calendar.Cal_Row_wid` -> `Sales.Date_wid`

Then I create 2 **slicers** `Date` and `Month`:

[image]

I would like to write a measure to calculate the Total `quantity_rcs` (which belongs to table `Sales`) for all order from the beginning up to current date (which characterized by `Date` and `Month`; both of them belong to `Calendars`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How this should work if you have multivalue slicer?

belove example for onevalue slicer where we are pointing to specific date (consider that you have a unique date column In calendar maybe "issue_date"):

```
Measure = 
var __date =  calculate(max(Calendar[issue_date]), FILTER(ALL(Calendar[Date] 
,Calendar[Month],Calendar[Year]),
Calendar[Date] = SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date]) &&
Calendar[Month] = SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Month]) &&
Calendar[Year] = YEAR(TODAY())
)
)
return

calculate( sum(Sales[quantity_rcs]), 
    FILTER(ALL(Calendar[issue_date]), 
        Calendar[issue_date] <= __date )
   )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The key part is `SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date])` :))